# What is NOS Hydrograph sounding data?

Tags: dem, bathymetry

How can sounding data be used for bathymetry when depth is positive? I have downloaded DEM (digital elevation model) as shown in the image below but need bathymetry data for H. All I have found for H is hydrograph sounding data which can be downloaded in xyz format but data does not match when trying to merge both DEM and sounding data in ArcGIS using spatial analyst/sample tool.
(green elevation less than 0. orange elevation=0)

[image]

[image]
It is demonstrated how DEM and sounding data does not match.

[H05455 XYZ Data](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/docucomp/page?url=http://surveys.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/NOS/hsmdb/H04001-H06000/H05455_hsmdb.xml&view=hydro/survey&header=none)

Comment: It is common for depths to be positive in hydro. Just multiply the values by -1, and apply any offset between datums.

Comment: I downloaded the bathymetry xyz H05455 NOS sounding data file. The file contains depth with both positive and negative.If we multiply negative number by -1 will it just be positive?      https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/docucomp/page?url=http://surveys.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/NOS/hsmdb/H04001-H06000/H05455_hsmdb.xml&view=hydro/survey&header=none

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the sounding data has an undefined vertical reference system. Without that, it's hard to answer where mismatch comes from.  Generally speaking, a DEM with have a geodetic (terrestrial) based vertical reference while soundings will use a tidal reference. Usually you just have to find the conversion for your location.  Based on the context, I am guessing that the soundings use mean low water as the vertical reference. If so 0 is usually 1-2 ft below MSL, which could explain your negative values

Answer (score 1):

The value on a chart tells the user the least depths that can be expected associated with some reference station (vertical datum) be it feet or meters.  The sign is irrelevant it is an absolute value.  If you are looking at a chart and it says 12 that means it is 12 units below the vertical [datum usually it is MLLW](http://www.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/mcd/learnnc_soundingdatum.html) because for navigation you want to know what the shoalest reading is. so in that example you can expect to have 12 units or greater clearance.

You can't symbolize based on the zero relationship as you have done.  Zero means you are on land.  But more importantly the data source is lacking a vertical reference, which makes it effectively useless.

Assuming we are talking about the States and NOAA data, which is collected for navigation not research. And [NOS Hydrographic Survey Data](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/bathymetry/hydro.html)